# Swift cast custom annotation to MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkannotation

In my app i used an annotation cluster (this one: [Cluster](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit) )
I made a custom annotation class MyAnnotations:

```swift
import UIKit
import MapKit
import ClusterKit

class MyAnnotations: NSObject, MKAnnotation, CKAnnotation{

weak public var cluster: CKCluster?


var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var name: String?
var size: String?
var user: String?
var owner: String?
var image: String?
var latLoc: Double?
var lonLoc: Double?
var itemId: String?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
}
```

Inside 
`func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

i need to access properties of MyAnnotations that are not part of MKAnnotation or CKAnnotation like size and owner but overtime i do:

```swift
let MyAnnotations = annotation as! MyAnnotations

let size = MyAnnotations.size
```

`i get error: Could not cast value of type 'NSKVONotifying_CKCluster' (0x60000011dc70) to 'app.MyAnnotations'`

Is there a way to access those properties?

EDIT:

```swift
  let annotation = MyAnnotations(coordinate: location)
                        annotation.coordinate = location
                        annotation.title = name
                        annotation.subtitle = specie
                        annotation.size = size
                        annotation.owner = owner
                        annotation.user = user
                        annotation.image = pictureurl
                        annotation.latLoc = lat
                        annotation.lonLoc = lon
                        annotation.itemId = itemId
```

Comment: There is definitely a typo in your code: you call your variable `MyAnnotations` and then try to call `MyAnnotation.size`. Also, do name a variable the same as a class name and use proper Swift naming convention (class: `MyAnnotations`, variable: `myAnnotation`).

Comment: i edited the typo, (a copy error)

Comment: Please show the code where you define annotation. It seems like annotation is of type `CKCluster`, which you obviously can't cast to `MyAnnotations`, since it is not a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

`MKAnnotation` is just a protocol with `coordinate` `title` and `subtitle`

On the other hand your custom class `MyAnnotations` you conform to these protocols `MKAnnotation, CKAnnotation`. These conformations can only offer what they have in their protocol signatures, not more.

In the callback you get an `annotation: MKAnnotation` which does not have `size` property. As soon as you cast this to your custom class you will get an error like that since it is not a subclass or anything else.

`size` information was never there for you to read. So casting does not help here. Whenever you force cast using `as!` you are basically silencing what compiler can do for you.

I would suggest you to create a mapper from those to your custom class and feed other data in this phase, boil all of them into one.

Comment: @HaVaNa7 I don't think there will be a generic example for your question. I assume your question is domain specific. The question is what is the source of information for fields like `size` and `owner` ? In this case definitely not the map. Another instance must be carrying that information.

Comment: the source is firebase, i made an array made of all objects and then added to the cluster manager

Comment: maybe i can filter that array comparing current annotation in func viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation to find other properties of object, is that a good idea?

Comment: That or anything similar wouls work depending on your implementation. Delegate method is the place you can get information about the annotation. If you need further data extraction, you can filter your firebase data source as you said and get the remaining information. Then you can construct your custom class and map those remaining values.

Comment: Could you helo answer a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193233/cluster-annotation-as-ckcluster-yielding-nil-clusterkit-mapbox?